# Strange jQuery $.each() Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm having strange problems with .each() not picking up certain text/html.

I have:

```
<ul class="errors">
   <li class="title">Please check the details you entered and try again.</li>
   <li id="title">Please supply a title</li>
   <li id="typeID">Please select a type</li>
   <li id="availID">Please select the availablilty</li>
   <li id="city">Please supply a valid city</li>
   <li id="postcode">Please supply a valid postcode</li>
   <li id="contactNum">Please supply a valid contact number</li>
   <li id="description">Please enter a description</li>
</ul>
```

And for the jquery:

```
$('.errors').children('^[id]').each(function(index){
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Now the problem is, jquery doesn't pick up the text/html for the "description" list item. No matter what I try.

Any ideas as to why this might happen?

Thanks,
TMP

UPDATE:
I've managed to find the problem. The fact that there is another element on the page with the same ID stopped it working. Strange really, as all the other list items are the same yet work just fine. Maybe a bug?

Cheers,
TMP

Comment: I'm not sure if `^[id]` is a [valid selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). What does it define?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbysh/cd59c/ - I am getting all the alerts I expect to get.

Comment: @pimvdb: It is not a valid selector as far as I know, but it produces identical results to `[id]`.

Comment: I should mention the list items are added by jquery when a button is pressed. But I've checked and all are added properly.

Comment: Make sure that the description element exists and is the only one with said id when you run the code. `alert( $('[id=description]').length );// anything but 1 is invalid`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are 2 elements with the same ID. That's the reason behind the $('.errors').children() selector, to make sure the content from the right one is selected, then added to the $('input#' + $(this).attr('id')) element. It's just strange that it won't grab the content for that item, but recognise it is there with the alert of "*index*: _BLANK_"

Answer (score 5):

```
alert(index + ': ' + $(this.text());
```

should be

```
alert( index + ': ' + $(this).text() );
```

You're missing a closing parenthesis after `this`.

**Edit**

With that typo fixed, I get the expected results: http://jsfiddle.net/xQyAt/

Comment: Ahh sorry that was a typo when posting on here. All other list items are read properly. Thanks.